# Can one measure two components of spin exactly by measuring two components of entangled, say, electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, observables, quantum-measurements

Of a single electron, two different components of spin can't be have simultaneously well defined values. But what if we entangle two of them and we measure, say, $(S_1)_z$ and $(S_2)_x$ simultaneously. Wouldn't you know $(S_1)_x$ and $(S_2)_z$ then at the same time too?

Comment: By entangled do you mean correlated?

Comment: @BillAlsept Yes. They meet, entangle their spins, and separate them over a fair distance.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I'm not very good at the hints game. Same now. :) If we measure s1z and s2x, don't we know all four?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Ah! You mean you *can* measure them both?

Comment: But what is the difference between correlated and entangled spins?

Comment: @BillAlsept If the spins are entangled the are correlated but if they are correlated they need not to be entangled.

Comment: all you need is correlation. Take two particles and randomly correlate their spins to be perfectly opposite. Even if you don’t know what the spins are you can measure one spin and automatically know what the other spin is. This is obvious, So (1)why do you need entanglement? (2) What is entanglement if not correlation? Anyone can physically explain how to correlate two particles, but no one knows how to entangle two particles.

Comment: This is not the question, I think. Further, you can for sure create entangled particles.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker What is physically different about creating entangled particles then correlating them?

Comment: @BillAlsept There is a mathematical definition of (bipartite) entanglement. If you want to call it correlation instead of entanglement, fine. But what's the point? You stressed that there is a difference by saying that correlated particles/states exist, but not entangled ones?!

Comment: @JasonFunderberker entanglement suggest there is some kind of connection between the two particles, when there is not. A correlated explanation is all you need to physically explain what’s going on.

Comment: @BillAlsept I can't see any *connection* mentioned in the definition of entanglement...

Comment: @JasonFunderberker When you explain it with simple correlation you can answer the OP’s question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have two (distinguishable) spin-$1/2$ particles prepared in the (Bell-) state

$$ |\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\lvert \uparrow\rangle \otimes \lvert \downarrow\rangle - \lvert \downarrow\rangle \otimes \lvert \uparrow\rangle \right)\tag{1} \quad ,$$

where $\lvert \uparrow\rangle$ and $\lvert \downarrow\rangle$ denote the spin-up and spin-down states in the $z$-direction. Let's say you've measured the $z$-component of the first particle and you obtained $+1/2$; then the state after the measurement is given by
$$ |\tilde \psi\rangle = \lvert \uparrow\rangle \otimes \lvert \downarrow \rangle  \quad .\tag{2} $$

So after this first measurement, the probability to obtain $+1/2$ for a measurement of the spin-$z$ component of the first particle is one and for the second particle $0$ (i.e., the probability to measure $-1/2$ for the second particle is $1$). Suppose you now measure the $x$-component of the second particle, and suppose you obtain $+1/2$, then the state after the measurement is

$$|\phi\rangle = \lvert \uparrow\rangle \otimes \lvert+\rangle \tag{3} \quad ,$$

where $\lvert +\rangle$ denotes the spin-up component in the $x$-direction.

To summarize: If you measure the spin-$z$ component  of the first particle and obtain $+1/2$ and if you measure the spin-$x$ component of the second particle and obtain $+1/2$, then the state after the measurements is given by $(3)$.

It is obvious now that the probability to measure $\pm 1/2$ for the spin-$x$ component of the first particle is $1/2$ and similarly for the spin-$z$ component of the second particle.

Here, we performed two local measurements, i.e. measurements on one of the subsystems each. But we can obtain the very same result with a measurement on the overall system via a joint measurement. To see this, note that since $[S_z \otimes \mathbb I, \mathbb I\otimes S_x] =0$, we can, at least formally, construct an observable$^\dagger$
$$C:=\sum\limits_{ij} c_{ij} \, P_i \otimes Q_j \quad , \tag{4} $$

where $c_{ij} \in \mathbb R$ are all different and $P_i$, $Q_j$ are orthogonal projectors defined through the following eigendecompositions:
\begin{align}
S_z &= \sum\limits_i s_i\, P_i  \tag{5}\\
S_x &= \sum\limits_j \tilde s_j \, Q_j \tag{6} \quad .
\end{align}
In particular, we have, for example
$$P_\uparrow \otimes  Q_+\, \lvert \uparrow \rangle \otimes \lvert + \rangle  = \lvert \uparrow \rangle \otimes \lvert + \rangle  \tag{7} $$
and thus

$$C\,\lvert \uparrow \rangle \otimes \lvert + \rangle = c_{\uparrow + }\, \lvert \uparrow \rangle \otimes \lvert + \rangle \quad . \tag{8}$$
We can further construct two functions, $f$ and $g$ such that $f(c_{ij})=s_i$ and $g(c_{ij}) = \tilde s_j$, leading to $S_z \otimes \mathbb I=f(C)$ and $ \mathbb I \otimes S_x=g(C)$.
Then, upon measuring $C$ in the state $(1)$, we obtain the result $c_{ij}$, from which we can read-off the $s_i$ and $\tilde s_j$. The state after the measurement is
$$ \propto P_i \otimes Q_j |\psi\rangle \quad . \tag{9} $$

Hence, by employing $(7)$ we see that a measurement of $C$ with measurement outcome $c_{\uparrow +}$ such that $s_\uparrow=+1/2=\tilde s_+$ yields the state $(3)$ as a post-measurement state.

---

$^\dagger$The proof of the corresponding theorem and the details of the calculations can be found in e.g. chapter $6$ of *Chris J. Isham, Lectures on Quantum Theory: Mathematical and Structural Foundations. Imperial College Press*.

Comment: Don't you mean two *in*distinguishable particles? Do you measure the two spin directions simultaneously (you refer to a first measurement)?

Comment: Well, I didn't want to bother with indistinguishability (for indistinguishable particles, it does not make sense to speak of particle one and two) and I think to use distinguishable particles is okay for this discussion. We could've talked about Qubits instead, for example. Regarding your second question: The scheme here uses two so-called local measurements. So e.g. Alice measures the spin of the first particle and Bob measures the spin of the second particle (think about e.g. the [EPR set-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox#Bohm's_variant)).

Comment: @Felicia I've updated the answer and added some notes regarding the joint measurement of the spins.